# Android Force Close with ActionBar and Support Library v7 in Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-support-library

i have a problem with my android application.

I'm using support Library v7 and i've imported the library as a project in Eclipse, configured the library in my project. changed the FragmentActivity for ActionBarActivity but when i launch the application using Android 2.3 Emulator Eclipse says that no compatible Emulator was found. In the manifest i have Minimum SDK 8 (Froyo 2.2) but no way.

When the app launches then it crashes inmediately. This is the log i got:

```
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1584)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  ... 35 more
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10102fd a=-1}
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:350)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:343)
11-13 21:11:37.637: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  ... 38 more
```

This is the activity_main layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#fca402"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the code of the MainActivity class:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
        private MenuItem menuItem;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
        public ActionBar actionBar;
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        private String[] mPlanetTitles;

         public static String usuarioID;
            public static String usuarioname;
            public static String claveusuario;
            public static String registrationID;

            ConnectionDetector cd;
            static Httppostaux post;
            static TextView textView;
            public static SessionManager session;

            JSONObject jsonobject;
            JSONObject jsonobject1;
            JSONArray jsonarray;
            ListView listview;
            ListViewAdapter adapter;
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
            static String IMAGEN = "imagen";
            static String QUIEN = "quien";
            static String REPORTE = "reporte";
            static String FECHA = "fecha";
            static String IMGS = "imgs";
            static String VIDEO = "video";
            static String CONTENIDOPOST = "contenidopost";
            Runnable Refresh;
            ImageButton refresh;
            ImageButton postear;
            int current_page = 1;
            boolean loadingMore = false;
        // Tab titles
        private String[] tabs = { "Reportes", "Cámaras", "Video en vivo" };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

            // Initilization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }

            /**
             * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
             * */
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });

    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

         // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
            // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

            // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
            // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this,                  /* host Activity */
                    mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                    R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                    R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                    ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                selectItem(0);
            }
       }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // on tab selected
            // show respected fragment view
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
          }

        @Override
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_load:
              menuItem = item;
             // menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.progressbar);
              //menuItem.expandActionView();
              new DownloadJSON().execute();
              break;
            case R.id.menu_reporte:
                  menuItem = item;
                  //menuItem.expandActionView();
                  Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ReporteActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("userId", usuarioID);
                    startActivity(i);
                  break;
            default:
              break;
            }
            return true;
          }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        //mTitle = title;
        //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String secciones = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            if (i == 2){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("¿Estás seguro de cerrar sesión en VideoTráfico.com?.")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Si, estoy seguro", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               new asynclogout().execute(usuarioID);
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("No gracias", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            if (i == 1){
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(),PrefsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 0){

            }
            //int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(secciones.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            //"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
           // ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
           // getActivity().setTitle(secciones);
            return rootView;
        }
}
```

Comment: At the bottom you have a resource-related crash message. Sometimes the Android tool chain messes up resource bundling. Try cleaning and re-building your project

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't work, the app continues crashing, in Android 4.2.2 works without problems. What could be? Do i nee to post the code of the app?

Comment: Ok... it's a bit of a shame that the stack trace does not contain the offending layout file's name but it looks to me like one of your layout files sets an incorrect drawable resource reference (hence the message "resource is not a drawable"). I guess you could figure out the offending file by running lint. In Eclipse right-click your app project -> Android Tools -> Run lint. After that look out for files in your project with warning triangles and error signs

Comment: Thanks for answer, i've added the layout code to the main post, also i've added my MainActivity code. Please help me! =D

Comment: Are you sure that's the right layout file? Your stack trace mentions at the bottom a TextView, which does not exist in your layout. What's the result of your lint run?

Comment: Thanks for answering, sorry for the delay, i was out of the town. I've removed the Navigation Drawer code from MainActivity and the app worked, even showed a drawer with no content. It's very weard.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is in R.layout.drawer_list_item which you've copypasted from the example app I believe. For attribute values containing "?android:attr/..." this template refers to API>10 specific resources. So you need to delete these attributes or use some relevant references.